# PrettyPrint class method signature lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a prettyprinter from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.1.1/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html

I am getting an error of class method signature lacks an accompanying binding with the following code:

```
data Exp = B Bool 
    | MyInt Int

data Doc ann 
 
class Pretty a where
    pretty :: Show a => a -> Doc ann 
    prettyList :: [a] -> Doc ann 
    
instance Pretty Bool where
    pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
    prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
```

I have made the following edits:

```
data Exp = B Bool 
    | MyInt Int

data Doc ann 
 
class Pretty a where
    pretty :: Show a => a -> Doc ann 
    prettyList :: [a] -> Doc ann 
    
instance Pretty Bool where
    pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
    prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
    pretty (B e1) = e1 
    prettyList [B e1] = e1
```

But now get the following errors:Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Exp’, Couldn't match expected type ‘Doc ann’ with actual type ‘Bool’

I just want to be able to print the Bool or [Bool]

Comment: You're mixing `Bool` (from `base`) and `B` (from `Exp`).

Comment: @Zeta, can you please show this fix in a code that will compile? I had tried to change the type and I just get into a loop of type errors

Answer (score 0):

In this block of Code

```
pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
pretty (B e1) = e1 
prettyList [B e1] = e1
```

You have promised a `Bool` but in your definition you have actually provided an `Exp`

What you probably want is

```
pretty :: Exp -> Doc ann
prettyList :: [Exp] -> Doc ann
```

You also have a problem in that what you implementation provides is not a `Doc` but the boolean value itself.  You need to convert that bool into a `Doc`.

Comment: say I wanted my original code to compile with your edits, how can I convert the bool into a Doc?

Comment: The only way to get a Doc is to use the `pretty` function so `pretty (B e1) = pretty e1`